# Display data from Custom Query(Joined tables) in liferay search container

Tags: mysql, liferay, liferay-6

I have followed [this wiki](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Custom+queries+in+Liferay+5.2) and have successfully built a custom query.

It works fine. I have used a join between tables.

My question is how do I display it on a jsp using liferay search container since className in search container requires one model class.

***EDIT:***
What I have tried till now is this:

```java
<%

getAttendanceData attName = new getAttendanceData();
List<Object[]> displayAttListName = AttendanceLocalServiceUtil.findAttendance();

ArrayList name = new ArrayList();
ArrayList title = new ArrayList();
ArrayList status = new ArrayList();
ArrayList remarks = new ArrayList();

for(Object[] att:displayAttListName) {

    name.add(att[0]);
    title.add(att[1]);
    status.add(att[2]);
    remarks.add(att[3]);
}

%>

<liferay-ui:search-container delta="20" emptyResultsMessage="No Results Found">
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results
            total="<%= displayAttListName.size() %>"
            results="<%= ListUtil.subList(displayAttListName , searchContainer.getStart(), searchContainer.getEnd()) %>"
        />

    <liferay-ui:search-container-row modelVar="search"
        className="java.lang.Object">


    <%
    for(Object displayName:name) {
    %>

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name='studName' value = '<%=String.valueOf(displayName)%>' href="">

        </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
    <%
    }
    %> 

    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>
    <liferay-ui:search-iterator/>
</liferay-ui:search-container>
```

What I have done above displays each of the 10 names 10 times in a column.
I want the names to appear on each new row. How shoould I modify the above code?

***EDIT 2***
Considering the `name` array defines earlier I did the following:

```java
<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="employee name" href = "">

    <%=name.getClass().getDeclaredFields().toString() %>

</liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
```

With the above, I am getting the result something like: `[Ljava.lang.reflect.Field;@195f1af` on each row.

Comment: What do you get from the 'Select'. Usually, in Service builder Custom Queries, you get an array of instances of one Class/entity/Table

Comment: @ yannicuLar:

I get data from two tables. I have taken a join:
select concat(stud.studFname , ' ' , stud.studLname) as studName , stud.studTitle, attendance.attRemarks, attendance.attStatus
 from student stud left outer join attendance attendance
 on stud.studId = attendance.studId and attendance.attDate = '2013-05-20';

I have taken inner join.

How do I display the result of the above query in liferay search container? 
Like I said I am not sure what to put as className

Comment: @ yannicuLar: :
Sorry i have taken left outer join.. not inner join.. like i said in previous comment

Comment: @seeya..you didnt follow the way i suggest u?

Comment: I didn't ever thought about creating a custom query that returns Object[] instead of some db Model's Class. And I probably won't do it anyway, but it's nice to know. +1 for the question

Comment: @yannicuLar:
I did not insert the field of second entity in the first like how it is suggested in liferay in action book. but i guess that is the method followed mostly. Read the comments below the answer given by Prakash K

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that the `name`, `title`, `status` and `remarks` field are all `String` (as per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683541/display-data-from-custom-queryjoined-tables-in-liferay-search-container/16718344#comment24017375_16683541)) so in the `for` loop you should cast the `Object` as a `String` and you don't need the four `ArrayList` for this.

Here is how the row tag would look like:

```
<liferay-ui:search-container-row className="java.lang.Object" modelVar="search">

    <%--
        Since an "Object[]" is nothing but an "Object", we first cast the "search"
        instance to an "Object[]" and then to a "String"
    --%>
    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name='name' value='<%= (String) ((Object[])search)[0] %>' /> 
    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name='title' value='<%= (String) ((Object[])search)[1] %>' /> 
    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name='status' value='<%= (String) ((Object[])search)[2] %>' /> 
    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name='remarks' value='<%= (String) ((Object[])search)[3] %>' /> 

</liferay-ui:search-container-row>
```

There you go, this should work.

A more cleaner way I think would be to have a POJO defined that would store these values and then the POJO's list can be returned. I have not tried the second approach though.

Another standard approach is to include extra fields in any one of the entity's `*Impl` and then returning the list of that entity, in your case I would assume you have `Student` and `Attendance` entities, so you can put the fields `status` & `remarks` in `StudentImpl` and then return a `List<Student>` or put `fname` in `AttendanceImpl` and return `List<Attendance>` from the finder method. (updated after [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683541/display-data-from-custom-queryjoined-tables-in-liferay-search-container#comment24087292_16718344))

Comment: I was just about to answer the same thing :-D

Comment: @Prakash K:
I's just trying it out and posted the same code ;)sorry if i misguided.
How should I display each element of the array? I have already told you what is happening. in the liferay search container wen I try to print array name , all the elements of the array are printed in one row. It happens for every row.
suppose if i have 10 records fetched from query(used join) then 10 rows are displayed each row having 10 records. i want each row to have one value from the database. How do i fetch the records in liferay search container when i have a join between tables? is my approach correct?

Comment: @Prakash K:
I was suggested to use Maps, hashMaps etc. my basic ques is, how do I display the resultset that i retrieved from custom query(i have applied left join between tables) in a liferay search container? i am confused since className requires a model class..

Comment: @Prakash K:
I forgot to mention. each array att[1] att[2] has many elements in it.. Since I have a join between tables, I am displaying many columns from two tbls and each of these att[i] has data from the columns retrieved from query...
So thats is why m having problem displaying data from these arrays in search container

Comment: @SeeyaK `attr[0]` will have a string value and is not another array. Yes though `attr` is an array.

Comment: @Prakash K:
Here is the code snippet:
<%
  getAttendanceData attName = new getAttendanceData();
 List<Object[]> ObjdisplayAttListName = AttendanceLocalServiceUtil.findAttendance();
 
  for(Object[] att:ObjdisplayAttListName) {
    System.out.println("Here is the first: " + att[0]);
 }

In above code when i printed att[0] it displayed all the names of people present in the database.. now i when i printed this att[0](by putting its contents in array calld "name")in search container, it prints all names in one row. i want each name on one row each. hw do i use a loop for this in search container?

Comment: @Prakash K:
Prakash your solution worked. Thanks a lot!! :) You suggested pojo class. One of the person in the forum had suggested me to use pojo but I coudnt get the correct answer with it. 
Also this is for sharing information with you. You must have read liferay in action. There the author has suggested a different approach. For joins he suggests to include the field from other entity into the first entity in the -impl class. Have you tried that approach?
Right now I am following your answr n have accepted it.. but do highlight me if u know about the approach suggested in the book

Comment: Oh yes, that is the standard approach in liferay to have the additional properties in any one of the entity's `-Impl`. We use that approach often.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30561/discussion-between-seeya-k-and-prakash-k)