# How to use custom bean class in search container in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I want to show some records in liferay portlet.
I have list of objects which I want to display and for that I am using `Searchcontainer` tag of liferay i.e. `liferay-ui:search-container` as follows:

```jsp
<liferay-ui:search-container delta="5" emptyResultsMessage="No Results Found" iteratorURL="<%= portletURL %>" >
   <liferay-ui:search-container-results total="<%= contents.size() %>" results="<%= ListUtil.subList(contents,searchContainer.getStart(),searchContainer.getEnd()) %>"> 
   </liferay-ui:search-container-results>

   <liferay-ui:search-container-row modelVar="content"  keyProperty="title" className="com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.DLFileEntry">
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name='Name' property="name" orderable="<%= true %>"></liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name='Title'   property="title" orderable="<%= true %>"></liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name='MimeType'   property="mimeType" orderable="<%= true %>"></liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name='CreatedDate'  orderableProperty="createDate"><%=ContentReportUtil.getCreatedDate(content) %></liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name='ModifiedDate'  orderableProperty="modifiedDate"><%=ContentReportUtil.getModifiedDate(content) %></liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>
   <liferay-ui:search-iterator/>
</liferay-ui:search-container>
```

Currently I am mapping myobject properties to `DLFileEntry` properties and creating List of DLFileentry objects from myobjects list but I know that is not good way please suggest the solution.

Comment: can't you use your object's full path instead of `DlFileEntry` as the value of `className` attribute?

Comment: Prakash, I have tried using that but It is not able to recognize my class. My class is simple pojo with properties which I wanted to show on page and getter setter for those properties.

Comment: Can you paste the code as to what you have tried, and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16718344/468763) might give you some idea.

Comment: Yes prakash I am able to use my custom pojo class thank you.

Comment: So can you give the answer and mark that as accepted? Thanks

Comment: done. hey could you please check this out when you get a chance? http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/25427525